# Learning to prove equality of sets and their cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> On $\mathbb R^2$ , define $(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2) \iff x^2_1 + y^2_1 = x^2_2 + y^2_2$. Find a transversal for $\sim$ and prove your answer.

> Partial answer: The equivalence class of a point $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ is given by $[(a,b)] = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = a^2 + b^2 \}$ meaning  the equivalence classes are concentric circles centered at the origin in $\mathbb R^2$. One possible transversal is $S = \{(0,r): r \ge 0\}$ -- set of representatives from distinct concentric circles. Another possibility for transversal is to choose any ray from the origin, fix a nonzero point $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ and obtain a transversal $\{(ra,rb) \in \mathbb R^2: r \ge 0\}$. To prove this, we wanna show $\mathbb R^2 = \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)] = \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(ra, rb)].$

I want to try proving equality of the given sets. So,

Suppose $(x, y) \in \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)].$ Then $(x, y) \in [(0, r)]$ for some $r \ge 0.$ Then $(x, y) \sim (0, r) \iff x^2 + y^2 = 0^2 + r^2 = r^2$ for some $r \ge 0.$ Now $[(ra,rb)] = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 =r^2(a^2 + b^2) \}$ for some $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$. In particular, $[(ra,rb)] = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 =r^2 \}$ for $(a, b) = (0, 1)$ meaning $(x, y) \in [(ra,rb)]$ for some $r \ge 0$ and some $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$ and so $(x, y) \in \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(ra, rb)]$ which proves $\bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)] \subseteq \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(ra, rb)].$ The other direction is very similar.

Assume $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$. Then $x, y \in \mathbb R$ for all $x, y$. In particular, $y = r$ for some $r \ge 0$ and so $(x, y) = (0, r)$ for some $r \ge 0$ meaning $(x, y) \in \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]$ and so $\mathbb R^2 \subseteq \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]$. The other direction is very similar.

Since equality is transitive, we have $\mathbb R^2 = \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(ra, rb)].$

---

Just for practice I will try showing $|\mathbb R^2| = |\bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]|.$

Assume $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and consider $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]$ as $f(x, y) = (0, r)$ for some $r\ge 0.$ Suppose $f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2) \iff (0, r_1) = (0, r_2)$. Since ordered pairs are equal iff the corresponding first components are equal and second components are equal, we have $r_1 = r_2$. Thus $(x_1, y_1) = (x_2, y_2)$ meaning $f$ is injective. Since $r$ is real, for any $(0, r) \in \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]$, we can find some $y \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $y = r.$ Also, $(0, y) \in \mathbb R^2$ for any real $y$. Thus there's some $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $f(x, y) = (0, r)$ for any $(0, r) \in \bigcup_{r\ge0}[(0, r)]$ meaning $f$ is surjective.

---

Do the proofs above work? If not, what are some alteratives? Thanks.

---

Edit: Turns out everything above is all sorts of incorrect. Anyone interested in corrections, can take a look at this reddit link below:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/l9ql09/showing_set_and_cardinality_equality/